# NLTK word Lemmatizer strange behavior - help in POS tagging - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, sentiment-analysis, lemmatization

Was trying to write a small program on sentiment analysis in python3. But while working with word lemmatizer saw strange conversion of "was" to "wa" which was completely unexpected. Below is my pre-process code - please help me to understand how can i avoid these issues. Also if POS tagging is must to get correct lemmatizer how do I include it correctly and efficiently in my preprocess function

```
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
stoplist = stopwords.words('english') + list(string.punctuation)

def preprocess(text):
    return [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in word_tokenize(text) if wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) not in stoplist and not word.isdigit() and len(word)>2]
```

The input text was basically the corpora from Multi-Domain Sentiment Dataset (version 2.0) and the line which caught my attention was below

```
<review_text> I just recieved my HDMI cable and am very impressed. The price is just what it should be about $5 and makes me wonder how somebody would spend over $100 for this cable at a store. The service was excellent and the cable arrived in 4 days! I highly recommend this cable. I just plugged it into my cable box and the other end into the TV and WOW what a great picture all around. The color is just so much more vivid using HDMI compared to component 3 wire connectors. Get this cable for your system and stay away from those high priced others </review_text>
```

And the output of the function after lemmatizer is

```
['recieved', 'HDMI', 'cable', 'impressed', 'price', 'make', 'wonder', 'somebody', 'would', 'spend', 'cable', 'store', 'service', 'wa', 'excellent', 'cable', 'arrived', 'day', 'highly', 'recommend', 'cable', 'plugged', 'cable', 'box', 'end', 'WOW', 'great', 'picture', 'around', 'color', 'much', 'vivid', 'using', 'HDMI', 'compared', 'component', 'wire', 'connector', 'Get', 'cable', 'system', 'stay', 'away', 'high', 'priced', 'others']
```

What got me bowled out completely is how "was" converts into "wa" ?? There are other interesting things like impressed stayed impressed and did not change to impress which may be because of POS?

If someone can help me with POS tagging in the same function will be great help

**-------------------EDITING TO POST SOLUTION and VALIDATION------------------**

Thanks for the kaggle link I used exactly the same function and getting better results. Just wanted to validate two things which may be is because I do not have correct understanding of the POS

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import string

nltk.data.path.append('C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data\\')

actualSent = "<review_text> I just recieved my HDMI cable and am very impressed. The price is just what it should be about $5 and makes me wonder how somebody would spend over $100 for this cable at a store. The service was excellent and the cable arrived in 4 days! I highly recommend this cable. I just plugged it into my cable box and the other end into the TV and WOW what a great picture all around. The color is just so much more vivid using HDMI compared to component 3 wire connectors. Get this cable for your system and stay away from those high priced others </review_text>"


wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
stoplist = stopwords.words('english') + list(string.punctuation)

def penn2morphy(penntag):
    """ Converts Penn Treebank tags to WordNet. Copied from kaggle post https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk"""

    morphy_tag = {'NN':'n', 'JJ':'a',
                  'VB':'v', 'RB':'r'}
    try:
        return morphy_tag[penntag[:2]]
    except:
        return 'n'

def lemmatize_sent(text): 
    # Text input is string, returns lowercased strings.
    return [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower(), pos=penn2morphy(tag)) 
            for word, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))]

def preprocess(text):
    return [word for word in lemmatize_sent(text) if word not in stoplist and not word.isdigit()]

token = preprocess(actualSent)
```

The above code gave me the below output

```
['review_text', 'recieved', 'hdmi', 'cable', 'impressed', 'price', 'make', 'wonder', 'somebody', 'would', 'spend', 'cable', 'store', 'service', 'excellent', 'cable', 'arrive', 'day', 'highly', 'recommend', 'cable', 'plug', 'cable', 'box', 'end', 'tv', 'wow', 'great', 'picture', 'around',  'color', 'much', 'vivid', 'use', 'hdmi', 'compare', 'component', 'wire', 'connector', 'get', 'cable', 'system', 'stay', 'away', 'high', 'price',  'others', '/review_text']
```

Now why the word "received" did not change to "receive" and "impressed" not change to "impress"

My ideas will get clearer if someone can help me understand the above two

Comment: Thank You. I was guessing it happened because of POS tagging. But was to wa is completely wacky :-). Can you please guide me to include the POS tagging in the preprocess function. I am confused already as to how I can include it and at the same time don't hit the performance of the code

Comment: I gave you a link above.

Comment: Ahh ok thank you - missed the link with Possible duplicate word - sorry. I will give it a shot

Comment: See https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

Comment: Thank You @alvas perfect and exactly the details I needed. I was struggling a little with the other link. Your explanation was quite useful. Thank You. I will try to follow it step by step and surely can fix my requirement